# Discord py message.createdat

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

im wondering how i can format the following:

```
async def sendmessage():
channel = client.get_channel(786258218925293629)
fetchMessages = await channel.history().find(lambda m: m.author.id == 627862713242222632)
print(fetched.created_at)
```

my end goal is to check if the message was sent within the last 30 minutes, and if it was, delete the message.

I need to format it into how many seconds ago the message was sent. Currently the output is:
2020-12-13 20:19:24.414000

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get how many seconds ago the message was sent by subtracting the `created_at` datetime object from the datetime object that represents the current time. The code to do this should look something like this:

```
import datetime # put this at the top of your code

...

async def sendmessage():
    channel = client.get_channel(786258218925293629)
    fetchMessages = await channel.history().find(lambda m: m.author.id == 627862713242222632)
    # i'm not sure where the fetched variable is from so i'm assuming you just forgot to include that bit of code
    msg_secs = (datetime.datetime.now() - fetched.created_at).total_seconds()
    print(int(msg_secs))
```

API References:
[datetime / timedelta object for datetime subtraction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds)

[created_at property of message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.created_at)

Comment: No problem. If this helped, don't forget to mark this question as solved!

Comment: Done ^ thanks a bunch, its working perfectly.